# 2D object array c sharp dynamic value allocation

Tags: c#, arrays, object, definition

I have initialized a 2d object array with dynamic size as follows;

```
        header.Value2 = new object[,] {
            { "col1", "col1", "col1", "col1", "col1", "col1", "col1", "col1", "col1" }
    };
```

Is there any way to set the inner object {"col1","".......} dynamically using variable as follows:

```
Object newobj = { "col1", "col1", "col1", "col1", "col1", "col1", "col1", "col1", "col1" };

header.Value2 = new object[,] {
            newobj
    };
```

Comment: You can call `header.Value2.SetValue(newobj, 0, 0);` Please be aware that this will place the new elements starting from arr[0,0] and if the length of the inner arrays are shorter than the passed array, it will overwrite the arr[1, n] as well

Comment: object does not contain a definition for 'SetValue' and no accessible extension method 'SetValue' accepting first argument of type object could be found

Comment: object Value2 { get; set; }

Comment: `((object[,])header.Value2).SetValue(newobj, 0, 0);` ?

Comment: Object newobj = new object[,] { { "col1", "col1", "col1", "col1", "col1", 
           "col1", "col1", "col1", "col1" } }; 
           


            ((object[,])header.Value2).SetValue(newobj, 0, 0);


says index was out of the bounds of the array.

Comment: You said you initialized the array. Haven't you initialized the array? Please provide full source code

Comment: i can initialize an array as well. I just want to set value to internal array in object for header.Value2.

Answer (score 0):

I think there might be some misconceptions.

```
header.Value2 = new object[,] {
        { "col1", "col1", "col1", "col1", "col1", "col1", "col1", "col1", "col1" }
};
```

this declares a2D array of fixed size with one column and 9 rows. There is no "inner object". You might be thinking of [jagged arrays](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/jagged-arrays) i.e. `object[][]`, since this will have a separate object for each row.

If you want to convert a 1D array to a 2D array then simply write a method to do it:

```
    public static T[,] To2DColumn<T>(T[] source)
    {
        var result = new T[1, source.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < source.Length; i++)
        {
            result[0, i] = source[i];
        }

        return result;
    }
```